# Articles/examples with test unit and active record

Tags: ruby, activerecord, testunit

I'm looking to write some unit tests that will let me build/test non-stubbed CRUD functions like I can in Rails but I want to use a minimal number of gems (test unit&active record).

Anyone know of any resources that might help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know of any resources specifically about this. To get active record working in a simple test you would just need to set up the connection details and your model classes assuming you have an existing database to work with that matches the active record conventions. Don't know what stage you are at but if you just need a simple example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'
require 'test/unit'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'sqlite3',
  :database => 'db/my.db'
)

# Assuming a table like:
# CREATE TABLE people (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, age INTEGER NOT NULL);
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class TestActiveRecord < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @bob = Person.create(:name => 'Bob', :age => 95)
  end

  def teardown
    @bob.destroy
  end

  def test_find_bob
    bob = Person.find_by_name('Bob')
    assert_not_nil(bob)
    assert_equal(95, bob.age)
  end
end
```

There are no other gems involved here other than those that active record itself depends on.

You'll have to work out what configuration settings you need depending on the type of database adapter you are using. If your database schema doesn't conform to the active record conventions then you will also have to specify some mappings in your model classes.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I ended up finding some simple examples similar to yours, but I didn't post them yet.  I guess I was looking for a best practice helper file like rails provides to manage my database properties.  Looks like I can just role my own.